# Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2(k+1)=\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)}{12}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

I have written the LHS using the sum of arithmetic sequence formula and got n((2+n^2+n^3)/2). After that I tried to do induction steps but don't know how to proceed or even if I am on the right track.

[Photo of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR7sc.jpg)

I would appreciate any guidance anyone is able to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Two comments: First, judging from your work, I assume you're allowed to assume closed expressions for $\sum k^2$ and $\sum k^3$? If that's true, I would also assume that induction is unnecessary: Those expressions hold true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so whatever you do with them will as well. Second, your expressions for those sums are incorrect. Look them up and try the correct ones. If you still have trouble, you can update your question with the requested MathJax :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your question, we have to find $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2}(k+1)$$.Let $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2}(k+1)$$. Now $k^{2}(k+1)=k^{3}+k^{2}$. Now just find $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}$$.
Now $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{3}=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^{2}$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2}=(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})$$. now the result of your summation will be $S=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^{2}+(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})$. Now take $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ common. So, $S=\frac {n(n+1)}{2}(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{2n+1}{3})$. So, $S=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{(3n^{2}+7n+2)}{6}$. So, $S=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)}{12}$.
Hence, proved.

Comment: I have done as per the method told by @Jean Marie.

Comment: Is my way correct @Jean Marie?

Answer (score 0):

My way: Let $f(x)=\frac14x^4-\frac16x^3-\frac14x^2+\frac16x$. We have $f(x+1)-f(x)=x^3+x^2$.Therefore $\sum_{k=1}^{n}[k^2(k+1)] =\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(k+1)-f(k)]=f(n+1)-f(1)=\frac{1}{12}n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)$

Comment: There is a simpler "way" : $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2(k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3+\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$ where the two sums have known closed form expressions : $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ and $(n(n+1)/2)^2$ resp.